# React animate containers height

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hqhz98?file=src/App.js)

Its a super simple app with four buttons and a text area.

When you click a buttons it loads different text

The text is different lengths so the grey container gets taller and shorter

Is it possible to animate the grey box when the text gets taller and shorter

```
const [text, setText] = useState(textArr[3])

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="nav">
        <button onClick={() => setText(textArr[0])}>
          One
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => setText(textArr[1])}>
          Two
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => setText(textArr[2])}>
          Three
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => setText(textArr[3])}>
          Four
        </button>
      </div>  
      <div className="text">
        {text}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I put a parent div with `overflow: hidden` applied to it then I used a `useEffect` to calculate the height of the text div when the text changes and then I set the height of the parent div to this height.

With `transition` on the parent div, it animates.

See demo here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-t7ctuf?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: To this answer I suggest making transition timing little more delay like, 0.3 will look good